# remove enteries from combobox where not = to table value vba access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a combobox listing of employees that needs to have former employees filtered out of the choices but still display them if they were selected as the employee for that particular order is there a simple way that with VBA I can say

For each entry if employees table . former employee = true remove them unless orders . orderID. employee = employeeID

so if Joe Schmoe is a former employee but it was his order leave him in the list

right now the list just removes former employees and the box is blank

Comment: you can use the `comboboxcontrol.RowSource = "SELECT..."` and then `.Refresh`

Comment: You would usually `Requery` the combobox, not `Refresh`. Refresh doesn't apply to a combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I've often wanted to do exactly what you are wanting but I haven't found a way to do it. I do have two work-arounds. I like to use both of them together.

1) In your query, put former employees at the bottom of the list, current employees at the top. This at least makes it simpler to select a current employee.

2) Use Code to prevent someone from saving a former employee selection in a new record.